# Date time conversion in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I have a payload containing 3 possible timezone formats (datetime and timezone abbr, timezone offset, timezone separate).
Example: "2022-01-20T15:00:00" tz = "CST" , "2022-01-20T15:00:00+05:30", "2022-01-20T15:00:00" tz = "Asia/Calcutta"

I need to convert the all 3 formats to UTC in dataweave.
Expected Output: 2022-01-20T15:00:00z

I am new to Dataweave. Please let me know if I need to call any third party libraries or can I do it with the existing DW capabilities.

Comment: You dont need to call any third party libraries. Just reading this https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-cookbook-change-time-zone documentation will help you get your result

Comment: Thanks Karthik for the documentation, what I am trying is 
{
    "datetime":"2021-01-20T15:00:00",       
    "timezone":"CET"
}
the above CET time should be converted to UTC.

Comment: ```"2022-01-20T15:00:00" >> "UTC"``` just try this with your other examples.

Comment: I need to write it as a DW function as a global function where I can refer it in any flow in mulesoft.

Comment: are you referring to something like this https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-create-module

Comment: I was able to achieve it using custom dw module and importing it into the DW script in the mule app.
[%dw 2.0

import * from dw::core::Dates

fun toUtcDateTime1(datetimeStr: String, timezoneStr: String) =
    
       (( datetimeStr as LocalDateTime) ++ timezoneStr ) >> "UTC"]

Answer (score 1):

Third party libraries are not needed. Use `>>` operator to convert the dates to UTC.

Dataweave code:

```
%dw 2.0
var date = "2022-01-20T15:00:00"
output application/json
---
date >> "UTC"
```

Output:

```
"2022-01-20T15:00:00Z"
```

Comment: This works only when the input string is the default format used to convert a String to a DateTime. It may not work for strings with other formats.

Comment: I was able to resolve it myself and prepared a blog post with more details.
https://medium.com/@piriyasivalingam/datetime-conversion-in-dataweave-2-0-mule-4-2105af1b86df